# String Implementation of a strcpy

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcpy

I am supposed to implement a strcpy function without using the library. I have written the code for that but there seems to be an error (possibly a memory leak but I'm not sure)

But if any of you can drop a hint, if it's a memory leak or not and how to fix it it'd be very helpful.

Header File:

Implementation file:

```
    #include "string.h"
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void copy (string *s1, string s2) {
      free((*s1));
      char *temp = malloc(strlen(s2 ->s) + 1);

      if(s2 -> s != NULL) {
      int i = 0;
      while(s2 -> s[i] != '\0') {
          temp[i] = s2 -> s[i];
          i++;
      }
      temp[i] = '\0';
      (*s1) -> s = temp;
      free(temp);
     }
    }
```

Setting a string works fine as far as I can tell, there seems to be a problem in the copying function.

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto string is the dreaded typedefd pointer.

Comment: Standard library code uses `size_t` for string lengths.  This code uses `int`, which differs in sign-ness and range.

Comment: With `void copy (string *s1, string s2)`, consider `free((*s1));` _after_ forming the new string.  `s2` might point into `s1`.

Comment: The parameter in the function is a pointer to a pointer, hence the dereferencing every time I use it.

Comment: Why ```copy``` is not just ```return set(s1, s2->s)```;

Comment: If you free ```free(temp);``` ```(*s1) -> s ``` is released too

Comment: ```(*s1) -> s = s;``` in ```Set``` is not valid, you are using the reference, the object depends of the char array

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto Wait.. But I wouldn't need temp once I've copied whatever's inside to (*s1) -> s

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto I would've chosen return set(s1, s2-> s) if I had a choice but I am supposed to use the procedures provided by the professor. It took me a while to figure that pointer to a pointer thing out and now I am stuck on the copy function.

Comment: ```temp``` and ```(*s1) -> s``` point to the same memory, if you free this memory, you destroy both. When you use free you are releasing the memory, pointers are only variables, like an int.

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto  But would it matter if I copy whatever temp is pointing to in (*s1) -> s and then delete the memory? Because now I have the copy and I don't need the original anymore?

Comment: You have a copy of the pointer, and is deleting the memory.

Answer (score 0):

A startup point is like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int len;
    char *s;
} string_t;

typedef string_t *string;

void set(string *s1, char *s);
void copy(string * s1, string s2);
void concat(string *s1, string s2);
void print(string s2);


void dispose(string s) {
    if (s != NULL) {
        if (s->s != NULL) free(s->s);
        free(s);
    }
}

void set (string *s1, char *s) {
    if (*s1 != NULL) dispose(*s1);
    *s1 = malloc(sizeof(**s1));
    (*s1)->len = strlen(s);
    (*s1)->s = malloc((*s1)->len + 1);
    char *temp = (*s1)->s;
    while ((*temp = *s) != '\0') {
        s++;
        temp++;
    }
}

void copy (string *s1, string s2) {
    set(s1, s2->s);
}


int main()
{
    string s = NULL;
    set(&s, "teste");
    printf("%s\n", s->s);
    dispose(s);
}
```

I think use `strlen` is not permitted.

Comment: Aside: `(*s1)->s != NULL` test not needed

Comment: I recommend `dispose(*s1);` after  the  `set()` `while` loop.

Answer (score -1):

There are many issues in your code depending on how you use it, e.g.

`copy` creates a copy of the string only to destroy (`free`) it immediately after. That's obviously not intended.

`copy` `free`s whatever `s1` is pointing to. This is only valid if it has been `malloc`ed before. Has it?

`print` destroys (`free`) the string after printing it. Is this intended?

`set` stores a pointer to argument `s` in `s1`. This will make `s1` invalid once the lifetime of `s` ends. (Matheus Rossi Saciotti)

Your question does not point out what the functions are intended to do and how they are used. But currently, `print` and `copy` are hardly useful.

Generally, a library should either do the memory management (`malloc`, `free` ...) entirely by itself or leave it to the caller entirely.

Comment: The free at the end of print was intended, it's supposed to free whatever memory we've allocated to the string. ** set(&s1, "Hallo); ** **print(s1);** This is how I tried testing the functions.

Comment: Is it wise? It means you cannot add `print`s for -- e.g. -- debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Setting and printing it out seems to work fine now. But I am still not fully comfortable with not knowing if I have memory leaks or not:

Copy function:

```
    void copy (string *s1, string s2) {
      //free((*s1));

      char *temp = malloc(strlen(s2 ->s) + 1);
      *s1 = malloc(strlen(temp));

      if(s2 -> s != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        while(s2 -> s[i] != '\0') {
            temp[i] = s2 -> s[i];
            i++;
        }
      temp[i] = '\0';
      (*s1) -> s = temp;
      free(temp);
     }
  }
```

Print function:

```
    void print(string s1) {
      if(s1 != NULL) {
      int i = 0;
      while (i < strlen(s1 -> s)) {
        printf("%c", s1 -> s[i]);
        i++;
      }
    } else {
    return;
   }

  }
```

Sorry about the indentations.

Comment: `strlen(temp);` is UB after `char *temp = malloc(strlen(s2 ->s) + 1);`.  Memory pointer to by `temp` is indeterminant.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(temp));` insufficient space, by 1, to save the _string_.  `(*s1) -> s = temp;
      free(temp);` is wrong as pointed out in other comments.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica but if i am to copy whatever's inside of temp to s1, i need to allocate enough memory: `(*s1) = malloc (sizeof(strlen(temp))`

Comment: Should have been  `(*s1) = malloc (strlen(temp) + 1)`.